# Mdx query for cube is returning different results for "With Member" if member identifier name is different

Tags: ssas, mdx, cube

I am firing mdxquery to fetch different tuple set combination for different cells using "With Member". My requirement is to query tuples with multiple dimensionality in a single mdx query.
As per my understanding member identifier is just an alias and it should not impact result of the query. But its returning different result set for the same query if i use separate member identifiers. The slicer where filter is also same.
My requirement is that I have a set of tuples and each tuple has different members Dimensions/attributes combination and I want to fire only one query to get data for each of these tuple sets. So I am using "With Member" option which allows having named member sets having different dimensionality.

Query 1 , Query 2, Query 3 is almost same only the member name used is different for all of them. Any help or suggestions is highly appreciated.

```
Query 1: 
With 
MEMBER [Account].[9] AS '([Account].&[500],[Department].&[102])' 
MEMBER [Account].[1] AS '([Account_Text].[Account_Text_Level].&[-1],[Account].&[161])' 
MEMBER [Account].[6] AS '([Account].&[500],[Account_Group].&[214])' 
MEMBER [Account].[10] AS '([Account].&[1])' 
MEMBER [Account].[13] AS '([Account].&[2881],[Company].&[173])' 
MEMBER [Account].[4] AS '([Company].&[1],[Company_Text].&[-1],[Account].&[500],[Account_Group].&[215],[Account_Text].[Account_Text_Level].&[-1],[Department].&[103])' 
Select 
{[Account].[9],[Account].[1],[Account].[6],[Account].[10],[Account].[13],[Account].[4]} 
Dimension Properties [Parent_Unique_Name] On Columns From [Adventure Works] 
Where ([BusinessCenter].&[1],[CalculatedDim].&[1],[CostCenter].&[1],[Department].&[1],[Geography].&[1],[ICSegment].&[1],
[ProductLine].&[1],[Reporting].[Level 1].&[14],[Company].&[1],[Scenario].&[1],[Time].&[2014])


Query 2:
With 
MEMBER [Test9] AS '([Account].&[500],[Department].&[102])' 
MEMBER [Test1] AS '([Account_Text].[Account_Text_Level].&[-1],[Account].&[161])' 
MEMBER [Test2] AS '([Account].&[500],[Account_Group].&[214])' 
MEMBER [Test10] AS '([Account].&[1])' 
MEMBER [Test13] AS '([Account].&[2881],[Company].&[173])' 
MEMBER [Test4] AS '([Company].&[1],[Company_Text].&[-1],[Account].&[500],[Account_Group].&[215],[Account_Text].[Account_Text_Level].&[-1],[Department].&[103])' 
Select 
{[Test9],[Test1],[Test2],[Test10],[Test13],[Test4]} 
Dimension Properties [Parent_Unique_Name] 
On Columns From  [Adventure Works]  
Where ([BusinessCenter].&[1],[CalculatedDim].&[1],[CostCenter].&[1],[Department].&[1],[Geography].&[1],
[ICSegment].&[1],
[ProductLine].&[1],[Reporting].[Level 1].&[14],[Company].&[1],[Scenario].&[1],[Time].&[2014]
)

Query 3:

With 
MEMBER [Company].[9] AS '([Account].&[500],[Department].&[102])' 
MEMBER [Company].[1] AS '([Account_Text].[Account_Text_Level].&[-1],[Account].&[161])' 
MEMBER [Company].[6] AS '([Account].&[500],[Account_Group].&[214])' 
MEMBER [Company].[10] AS '([Account].&[1])' 
MEMBER [Company].[13] AS '([Account].&[2881],[Company].&[173])' 
MEMBER [Company].[4] AS '([Company].&[1],[Company_Text].&[-1],[Account].&[500],[Account_Group].&[215],[Account_Text].[Account_Text_Level].&[-1],[Department].&[103])' 
Select 
{[Company].[9],[Company].[1], [Company].[6],[Company].[10],[Company].[13],[Company].[4]} 
Dimension Properties [Parent_Unique_Name] On Columns From  [Adventure Works]  
Where ([BusinessCenter].&[1],[CalculatedDim].&[1],[CostCenter].&[1],[Department].&[1],[Geography].&[1],[ICSegment].&[1],
[ProductLine].&[1],[Reporting].[Level 1].&[14],[Scenario].&[1],[Time].&[2014],[Account].&[1])
```

Comment: Can you attach the results. Secondly what are you trying to achive with this?

Comment: I have a set of tuples and each tuple has different members and I want to fire only one query to get data for each of these tuple sets. So I am using "With Member" option which allows having named member sets having different dimensionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer is based on your comment.

> I have a set of tuples and each tuple has different members and I want
>   to fire only one query to get data for each of these tuple sets. So I
>   am using "With Member" option which allows having named member sets
>   having different dimensionality. – Sudi

You problem deals with the concept of dimensionality and hierarchility. Hierarchility says that all tuples in a set should contain the same dimension-hierarchies, Dimensionality says they must be in the same order. So if a tuple is missing a member you use its default member in the query, to satisfy the property. This will not effect the result as this is what the query processor does for each dimesnion that you leave out in your tuple. Your query will be like.

```
Select 
{
([Account].&[500], [Department].&[102],                       [Account_Text].[Account_Text_Level].defaultmember, [Account_Group].[YourHierarchy].defaultmember, [Company].[YourHierarchy].defaultmember,[Company_Text].[YourHierarchy].defaultmember),
([Account].&[161], [Department].[Youhierarchy].defaultmember, [Account_Text].[Account_Text_Level].&[-1],         [Account_Group].[YourHierarchy].defaultmember, [Company].[YourHierarchy].defaultmember,[Company_Text].[YourHierarchy].defaultmember),
([Account].&[500], [Department].[Youhierarchy].defaultmember, [Account_Text].[Account_Text_Level].defaultmember, [Account_Group].&[214]                       , [Company].[YourHierarchy].defaultmember,[Company_Text].[YourHierarchy].defaultmember),
([Account].&[1],   [Department].[Youhierarchy].defaultmember, [Account_Text].[Account_Text_Level].defaultmember, [Account_Group].[YourHierarchy].defaultmember, [Company].[YourHierarchy].defaultmember,[Company_Text].[YourHierarchy].defaultmember),
([Account].&[2881],[Department].[Youhierarchy].defaultmember, [Account_Text].[Account_Text_Level].defaultmember, [Account_Group].[YourHierarchy].defaultmember, [Company].&[173]),
([Account].&[500], [Department].&[103],                       [Account_Text].[Account_Text_Level].&[-1],         [Account_Group].&[215]                       ,[Company].&[1]                          ,[Company_Text].&[-1])
} 
Dimension Properties [Parent_Unique_Name] On Columns 
From [Adventure Works] 
Where 
([BusinessCenter].&[1],[CalculatedDim].&[1],
[CostCenter].&[1],[Department].&[1],
[Geography].&[1],[ICSegment].&[1],
[ProductLine].&[1],[Reporting].[Level 1].&[14],
[Company].&[1],[Scenario].&[1],[Time].&[2014])
```

Edit: based on comment below

Take a look at the

```
select 
[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
on columns,
([Date].[Calendar Year].&[2012],[Product].[Category].&[1])
on 
rows 
from [Adventure Works]
```

Result
[image]

Second tuple

```
select 
[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
on columns,
([Date].[Calendar Year].&[2012],[Customer].[Country].&[United States])
on 
rows 
from [Adventure Works]
```

Result:
[image]

Third tuple

```
select 
[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
on columns,
{
([Customer].[Gender].&[F],[Product].[Category].&[3])
}
on 
rows 
from [Adventure Works]
```

Result
[image]

Now lets combine them

```
select 
[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
on columns,
{
([Date].[Calendar Year].&[2012],[Product].[Category].&[1],[Customer].[Country].defaultmember,[Customer].[Gender].defaultmember),
([Date].[Calendar Year].&[2012],[Product].[Category].defaultmember,[Customer].[Country].&[United States],[Customer].[Gender].defaultmember),
([Date].[Calendar Year].defaultmember,[Product].[Category].&[3],[Customer].[Country].defaultmember,[Customer].[Gender].&[F])
}
on 
rows 
from [Adventure Works]
```

Result
[image]

Comment: Hi MoazRub, thanks for your answer. But in my case I may have combination of attributes and dimensions. If there were only dimensions to maintain the hierarchility I could have added default dimensions but for attributes there are no default attributes. So the only option feasible was to use '"With Member"" . But I am unable to understand why this gives different result with different member aliases. Appreciate any help.

Comment: @Sudi I guess i was not able to explain myself. Take a look at the edit

Comment: But here all the members are dimensions. If we have attributes or attribute hierarchy where there is no default members defined so how do we query the same for attributes.

Comment: @Sudi for example "[Date].[Calendar Year].&[2012]" is not just a dimension, "Calendar Year" is the attribute of "Date" dimesnion. As far as attributes hierarchy goes it is translated to underlying attribute. You will always have a defaultmember value. Usually it is "All" else the one you define, else the first member.

Comment: Use the member [All] instead of defaultmember. ALL is the standard member to use.

Comment: @whytheq there are times when all is not defined. default will translate to all whenever all is defined. Else it will pick the first member.

Comment: Thanks @MoazRub and whytheq I think having default member to maintain hierarchility solves my problem. Also in our case, by default [All] is set as default member in case of attributes/attribute hierarchy. So we can use ALL as default member.

Comment: @Sudi you are welcome. Since the answers helps you solve the problem you may consider marking it as answer and/or upvoting it.

Comment: Upped answer as you have spent a long time exploring this. Well done.

Comment: @whytheq absolutely bro. MDX is love.